# Почему запрос INSERT INTO не добавляет записи?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$link) {
    exit("<P>B настоящий момент сервер базы данных недоступен, поэтому
    корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</Р>");
} else {
    echo ("Соединение установлено");
}
$db = mysql_select_db(db, $link);
if (!$db) {
    exit("<P>B настоящий момент база данных недоступен, поэтому
    корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</Р>");
} else {
    echo ("Соединение установлено");
}
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'locomotivs' ('№_locomotive','model','data_vipuska') VALUES ('6','ВЛ','1990-10-10')");
if ($result) {
    echo ("Добавление прошло успешно");
} else {
    echo ("Данные не были добавлены");
}
?>
```

Почему не добавляет записи в таблицу ?
Спасибо всем, работает, удалил таблицу и заново создал

Comment: Название таблицы и полей должны быть в обратных кавычках, а не в одинарных. Либо пишите вообще без кавычек:

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO locomotivs (idlocomotive, model, data_vipuska) VALUES ('6','ВЛ','1990-10-10')");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
$db = mysql_select_db(db, $link);
```

указанный в скобках параметр **db** без знака **$** является константой, она объявлена где-нибудь выше или возможно это название базы данных? Во втором случае нужно заключить название в ковычки.

2.

после строки

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'locomotivs' ('№_locomotive','model','data_vipuska') VALUES ('6','ВЛ','1990-10-10')");
```

добавьте

```
echo mysql_error();
```

тем самым вы увидите ошибку, которую вам отправляет MySQL и, думаю, сами поймете в чем дело.

*P.S.*

использование спец знаков в названиях баз данных, таблиц, колонок, полей не есть хорошо и может влечь за собой трудноопределяемые ошибки

Comment: при добавление echo mysql_error(); выводится
 Unknown column 'В№_locomotive' in 'field list'

Comment: вот, проблема, как минимум, локализирована, в php нет ошибок - MySQL не распознает название колонки номера локомотива, непонятно откуда взялась "B" в названии. Проверьте код, а лучше попробуйте в БД саму колонку переименовать допустим в 'locomotive_no', а также изменить название колонки в sql запросе

Comment: изменил название колонки на idlocomotive, теперь такая ошибка Unknown column '6' in 'field list'

Comment: у вас значения поменялись с названиями столбцов таблицы, проверьте SQL

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `locomotivs`
          (`№_locomotive`,`model`,`data_vipuska`) VALUES ('6','ВЛ','1990-10-10');");
```

Ещё ошибка тут:

```
$db = mysql_select_db(db,$link);
```

А надо:

```
$db = mysql_select_db( 'name_of_my_database', $link );
```

Comment: если честно, не понял

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: название бд принципиально надо писать в '' ? или название базы db ему не подходит ?

Answer (score 0):

лишняя точка с запятой в строке запроса

Comment: не помогает это

Comment: попробуйте echo mysql_error($link);
что там кажет?

Comment: Unknown column 'В№_locomotive' in 'field list'

Comment: по ходу неправильно указано название поля в запросе, посмотрите как оно точно называется в таблице (desc locomotivs; - в mysql клиенте)

Comment: скопировал название из базы, вставил в запрос, тоже самое, может символ № не читается ? Поменял №_locomotive на idlocomotive выдало Unknown column '6' in 'field list'