# Переменная не вставляется в БД

Tags: php, sql

В таблице, в полях, где вставляются переменные пусто.

Вот код:

```
<?php

$handle = @fopen("1.txt", "r");
$buffer = array();

if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer[] = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
      //  echo $buffer.'<br>';
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Ошибка: fgets() неожиданно потерпел неудачу\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$x=0;
foreach ($buffer as $value) {
    $adress = $buffer[$x];
    echo $adress;
    $x++;

    $name = $buffer[$x];
    //    echo $name;
    $x++;

    $lat = $buffer[$x];
    //    echo $lat;
    $x++;

    $lng = $buffer[$x];
    $x++;

    $photo = $buffer[$x];
    $x++;

    $type = $buffer[$x];
    $x++;
}

$connect=mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
if ( !$connect ) die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");

$db="map";
mysql_select_db ( $db ) or die ("Невозможно открыть $db");

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `markers` ORDER BY `markers`.`id` ASC ";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `markers` (marker, name, address, lat, lng, photo, type ) VALUES ('batarei', 'Батарейки', '$adress' , '$lat', '$lng', '$photo', '$type')");

if ($result) {
    echo ("Добавление прошло успешно 1");
} else {
    echo ("Данные не были добавлены 2");
}

echo mysql_error();
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: начните лучше с того, что у вас находится в файле и в каком виде, и какого он объема.

Comment: думаю, вам это поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/53127/Почему-запрос-insert-into-не-добавляет-записи

Comment: файл размером 16кб внутри построчно: вул. Данилевського, 32Б
Батарейки
50.00907365246954
36.22150275767217
 images/nophoto.png
Підприємство/організація: ТО «Два товариша». Контактні дані: тел. 700 03 09. Мейл людини, що додала пункт: brinko.vitaliy@mail.ru. Коментар: Прийом батарейок проводиться з 9.00 до 18.00
вул. Донець-Захаржевського, 6/8
Батарейки
49.9941233
36.2339813
 images/nophoto.png
Магазин «Клуб мандрівників». тел. 755-80-53

Comment: @13zone и с кавычками вы что-то намудрили, echo mysql_error(); добавьте, посмотрите ответ mysql сервера

Comment: @13zone нам вряд ли что-то даст то,что хранится внутри файла. посмотрите данные, записанные в переменных, разберитесь с кавычками и посмотрите, что отвечает сервер, может, он какой-то столбец не находит, например...

Comment: ошибок нет, данные вставлены успешно... но.. в таблице в полях где вставляются переменные пусто.. есть только ид и два поля указанных вручную

Comment: используйте [edit] чтобы отредактировать вопрос. уберите свой цикл чтения и используйте [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php) и `array_slice()` для чтения данных

Comment: А почему у вас insert не в цикле ? вы сейчас по очереди читаете в переменные все строки, а потом, когда у вас в переменных остались данные последней строки делаете insert. И лучше перейдите на MySQLi/PDO и используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php А иначе кавычки внутри данных вам все сломают.

Comment: ура... все отлично работает. нужно было только поменять кодировку принимаемого файла. проблема решена